# Using webpack dev server, how to proxy everything except "/app", but including "/app/api"

Tags: proxy, webpack-dev-server

Using webpack dev server, I'd like to have a proxy that proxies everything to the server, except my app. Except that the api, which has an endpoint under my app, should be proxied:

- `/myapp/api/**` should be proxied
- `/myapp/**` should not be proxied (any
- `/**` should be proxied

The following setup does this using a bypass function, but can it be done declaratively, using a single context specification?

```js
proxy: [
    {
        context: '/',
        bypass: function(req, res, options) {
            if (
                req.url.startsWith('/app') &&
                !req.url.startsWith('/app/api')
            ) {
                // console.log ("no proxy for local stuff");
                return false;
            }
            // console.log ("Proxy!")
        },
        // ...
    },
],
```

Answer (score 15):

According to https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy webpack dev server uses http-proxy-middleware and at its documentation (https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#context-matching) you can use exclusion.

This should be working in your case:

```js
proxy: [
    {
        context: ['**', '/myapp/api/**', '!/myapp/**'],
        // ...
    },
],
```